# How debug reported exception outside my code in ListView

Tags: android, listview

-In my app I have 2 ListView in different activities.

-I get exception reported from users in play developeres console.

-I get 7-10 reports per day. App has 500 downloads per day.

-Reports are from all versions of Android and all devices. There is no pattern.

-In exception trace is not referenced my code.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren
```

Type 1:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren (ListView.java:1578)
  at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForTap.run (AbsListView.java:3450)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5550)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:955)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

Type 2:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren (ListView.java:1565)
  at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForTap.run (AbsListView.java:3237)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:808)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5345)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:828)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:644)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

Type 3:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren (ListView.java:1593)
  at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForTap.run (AbsListView.java:3623)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5790)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1015)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

Comment: Maybe we could have a look at the code that is producing these errors?

Comment: Its going to be your getView function.  Post it, and any xml it inflates

Comment: I have 2 list view in my app and and getView() has about 2000 lines of code.

Comment: @user3782779 :: "getView() has about 2000 lines of code"?? Wow!!

Comment: @Barns52 Not in getView() Directly, but getView() call functions that has a lot of code. I would to upload the code of the entire app.

Comment: Does the listview get modified in anyway after the adapter has been initialized? Does it get updated, rows deleted, rows added?

Comment: Rows not deleted, no added, list view size is constant value. I call notifiDateSetChanged() multiples times to update data of getView(). All times from ui thread.